# Aurelia - disable reset on router-view

Tags: view, render, aurelia, router, reset

My forms keeps resetting if I change tabs on router-view, is there a way to prevent this (if not what's the alternative)

```
export class App {
configureRouter(config, router) {
config.title = "Aurelia";
config.map([
  { route: ["", "dashboard"], name: "dashboard", moduleId: "HTML/viewmodels/dashboard", nav: true, title: "Dashboard", settings: "icon-home" },
  { route: "addons", name: "addons", moduleId: "HTML/viewmodels/addons", nav: true, title: "Addons", settings: "icon-file" },
  { route: "error", name: "error", moduleId: "HTML/viewmodels/error", nav: true, title: "Error", settings: "icon-info-sign" }
]);

this.router = router;
console.log(router);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a state persisting issue. The easiest solution is to store state in:

- The parent view
- A non-view related singleton class (or static variables)
- Localstorage persisting (possibly coinciding with the previous option)

---

**The first way to do it: save it in the parent view.**

For example, you could create a cache inside the `App` class:

```
export class App {
  formData = {};

  configureRouter(config, router) {
    { route: ["", "dashboard"], [..snip..] settings: { formData: this.formData, icon: 'icon-home' } }
  }
}
```

Inside your view, you can then do:

```
activate(params, routeConfig) {
  this.formData = routeConfig.settings.formData;
  this.icon = routeConfig.settings.icon;
}
```

And in the HTML, just bind it to `formData`:

```
<input type="text" value.bind="formData.text" />
```

This kind of assumes, that the whole `App` revolves around that form. Otherwise, it wouldn't really make much sense to store it in there.

That's one way to do it, anyway (the first one I pointed out in the list).

---

**The other way to do it: singleton.**

Create a new class called `AppState` or something along those lines.

```
export class AppState {
  formData = {};
}
```

Then in your view, you should import and inject it:

```
import { AppState } from './app-state';

export class YourView {
  static inject = [AppState];

  constructor(appState) {
    this.appState = appState;
  }
}
```

And then in your HTML, you can bind it like so:

```
<input type="text" value.bind="appState.formData.text" />
```

---

**Or third way: a static class.**

Create a new class called `AppState` or something along those lines.

```
export class AppState {
  static formData = {};
}
```

Then in your view, you should import and inject it:
import { AppState } from './app-state';

```
export class YourView {
  AppState = AppState;
}
```

And then in your HTML, you can bind it like so:

```
<input type="text" value.bind="AppState.formData.text" />
```

Comment: What if I want all my tabs to be persistent state and they have instances of  some other classes I want preserve as well

_Edit:_ Also isn't singleton a default way of class operating

Comment: You can make a singleton or a static class to preserve all of that. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: I added the explanations for the other two methods as well. I reccommend using a properly named singleton personally.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping they have out-of-a-box solution, this adds a layer of complexity. Will try it out

Comment: Dependency injection basically is a 'out of the box' solution. That's pretty much the same way you would have to do it in every other platform as well (mobile etc). To persist state, you need some solid object that does not get destroyed (views get created when needed and destroyed when they're no longer used). :)

Comment: Excellent solution, Travo.